# Stop a Flash moving object with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am used AS3 to programme an obect moving from certain point in the screen to another at a certain speed. I tried with different codes but i can't really achieve what I am looking for...
Now i am working with the following code:

```
var xVelocity:Number = 8;

addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, onVelocity);

function onVelocity (eventObject:Event):void
{
    animal0.x +=  xVelocity;
    animal0.y +=  yVelocity;
}
```

The object moves perfectly but i can't make it stop in the position x that i want...it keeps on moving till it reaches the end of the screen...
How can i make it stop at the point I want? or if you have a better way to do that....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the distance formula to calculate how far the object is from its destination, then if it's close enough, lock it in to your exact coordinates.

```
var dist:Number; // The distance between the object and its destination
var threshold:int = 3; //How close it has to be to snap into place
function onVelocity (eventObject:Event):void
{
    animal0.x +=  xVelocity;
    animal0.y +=  yVelocity;
    dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDest - animal0.x,2) + Math.pow(yDest - animal0.y,2));
    if(dist < threshold)
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onVelocity);
        animal0.x=xDest; // Locks the object into the exact coordinates
        animal0.y=yDest;
    }

}
```

I had the exact same issue with a game I'm creating, and this is how I solved it.

Comment: wow...that's really good. It looks complicated at first but you explained it perfectly...thanks. That's really heloful!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the animal is moving across the screen left to right, the following code will stop it from moving once it reaches the xDest.

```
var xVelocity:Number = 8;
var xDest = 300;//Destination point along X axis

addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, onVelocity);

function onVelocity (eventObject:Event):void
{
    if(animal0.x < xDest)
    {
        //only move animal0 so long as it has not reached the destination
        animal0.x +=  xVelocity;
        animal0.y +=  yVelocity;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Flowers You're welcome. Please mark answers as accepted (and give upvotes to helpful answers) so others know that they are solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a tweening engine I think the greensock package is your best option.
http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/